# How should i do to move the checkbox to the same row as the display field?

Tags: mysql, eclipse

[Web page display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukx7R.jpg)

I want to be able to have a checkbox on the action column of every rows of data display.

#### Code

[image: Code]

This is my code. The problem is that the checkbox is creating its own row at the bottom of the row that i want it to be at. What should i do, so that the checkbox is at the same row as "raise it up"?

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your source code in the body of the question.